# Is there a finite number of power armor sets in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing Fallout 4 on survival mode and have been trying to scavenge every piece of equipment that helps keep me from dying. To this effect, I've been arming my settlers with sets of power armor and strong weapons. They're too likely to be killed by raiders otherwise and leave my settlements undefended.

While I can find some decent weapons on most enemies I kill the power armor frames are a little more scarce to find. I've seen power armor frames for sale at a few merchants. Does this mean that as long as I have the caps I can buy more sets upon merchant restock, or is their supply finite?

Comment: The only thing endangering your settlers is *you* and any aoe damage *you* cause. Unless survival mode changed that? [Can my settlers (especially the supply line units) die?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242861/can-my-settlers-especially-the-supply-line-units-die)

Comment: There's got to be at least some 50 sets. I always ended up with more of them that I knew what to do with. You only need a couple of them yourself after all, unless you want to equip all the companions in power armor too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four of the vendors in the game sell one Power Armour Frame each.  Once you buy the Power Armour Frame they have available, they will **not** restock.

> Rowdy (Atom Cats garage), Arturo Rodriguez (Diamond City), KL-E-0 (Goodneighbor), and Proctor Teagan (the Prydwen)

*However*, it **is** possible to get infinite Power Armour Frames.  All you need to do is find a location with a respawning enemy who uses Power Armour (e.g. [Revere Beach Station](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Revere_Beach_station)), and make the NPC exit the Power Armour before you kill them (e.g, pickpocketing their Power Core, or shooting it with a weapon to destroy the Power Core without killing the NPC)

However, this usually leaves the Power Armour Frame marked as owned by the NPC — despite their death — meaning that, every time you climb into the Power Armour, [it will count as Stealing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286292/how-do-i-un-steal-power-armor), which may prevent your Settlers from using them.